# Duplicate Column Name lock_status

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have added lock_status column in database and in onUpgrade() Alter Table,but When I try to open my App, it force stops with the following error.
What should I do in onUpgrade(), I have updated my database 4th time with new column.
Help is highly Appreciated.

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: lock_status (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN lock_status INT
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
  at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Adapter.DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(DatabaseHelper.java:89)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
  at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Adapter.DatabaseHelper.getAllNotes(DatabaseHelper.java:170)
  at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Activity.MainActivity.setupNotesAdapter(MainActivity.java:603)
  at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:256)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
```

My Database Code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String LOG=DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=4;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="NotesDB";
public SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public static final String TABLE_NOTES="notes";
public static final String TABLE_PASSCODE = "passcodetable";

public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE="title";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT="content";
public static final String KEY_UPDATED_AT="updated_at";
public static final String KEY_COLOR="color";
public static final String KEY_TAG="tag";
public static final String KEY_FAVOURITE="favourite";

public static final String KEY_LOCKSTATUS = "lock_status";
public static final String KEY_PASSCODE_ID="passcode_id";
public static final String KEY_PASSOCDE = "passcode";
public static final String KEY_PASSCODE_STATUS = "passcode_status";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE="CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLE_NOTES+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +KEY_TITLE+" TEXT, "
        +KEY_CONTENT+" TEXT, "
        +KEY_UPDATED_AT+" BIGINT, "
        +KEY_COLOR+" INT, "
        +KEY_FAVOURITE+" INT, "
        +KEY_LOCKSTATUS+" INT"+" )";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PASSCODE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        +TABLE_PASSCODE+"("+KEY_PASSCODE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +KEY_PASSOCDE+" TEXT"+" )";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PASSCODE);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    onUpgrade(paramSQLiteDatabase, paramInt1, paramInt2);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 3){
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN color INT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN favourite INT");
    }
    if (newVersion > oldVersion){
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN lock_status INT");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                +TABLE_PASSCODE+"("+KEY_PASSCODE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +KEY_PASSOCDE+" TEXT"+" )");
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to add KEY_LOCKSTATUS in CREATE TABLE and in ALTER TABLE too

Comment: @LucasPaolillo But when user installs the app for the first time then it will call onCreate(),so all columns should be present their, but when the user updates the app, it calls onUpgrade().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as written now will try to add the column lock_status **every** time your database version increases. You have an if statement checking for old version < 3, then immediately have a second check for new version greater than old version. That second check is always going to be true when your version increases, so it will always try to add the column.

Suppose you added the lock_status column in version 4. Then a correct test would be

```
if (oldVersion < 4) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

The problem is not (necessarily) that you add lock_status in your create and in your upgrade, as suggested in a comment. If the database already exists, the create method will not be called. If the database does not exists yet, the update method will not be called.

Comment: I tried adding if(oldVersion < 4) previously, it won't work.

Comment: When you step into that code in the debugger, what is it showing you for oldVersion and newVersion?

Comment: I will have to see that..wait

Comment: @PrasadShirvandkar, the solution seems to be right... the problem can be with your device version of app, that has already add the column to db because of the wrong way you are doing the if before. Try to remove app from smartphone, and downgrade the  DATABASE_VERSION to 3 and use this solution. After that, upgrade Database_version to 4 and post and i think it will work.

Comment: What Lucas has suggested is the path I am directing you down. The SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate/onUpgrade/onDowngrade mechanic can get you into trouble during development if you don't keep a weather eye to your database version. What I suspect happened is you updated your db code but left the version at 3 (or 2, or 1), deleted the app from your device, and recompiled/reinstalled. The table gets built with the lock_status column. You make further changes to your code, update the db version, and place the logic test around your alter. The test passes but the column is already there, so ... exception

Comment: @Eliodorus Solved it.. included oldversion in switch case and provided cases for that almost the same what you suggested and then it seems like either my Android Studio was not building the Signed apk properly or it was repeatedly executing onUpgrade() method. Anyways Solved the Error.

Comment: I have changed a DATA_TYPE of one column, so do I need to include alter that in onUpgrade() method or it is okay to not include that.

Comment: @Prasad That's a judgement call. If you've distributed the app already, then make it an upgrade (and remember to increment your db version). If you are still in development mode, you could just rewrite your create table statements, wipe the apk from all devices, and redeploy - it will look like a new install so your onCreate code will be called.

Comment: @Eliodorus Now it is giving this error -_- 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: passcodetable (code 1)

Comment: @Prasad Sorry been offline last few days. I'll look and respond shortly.

Comment: Can you provide your current code? Do not paste it over the original code (as I'd like to compare the two). My suspicion is that you have another version problem.

Comment: @Eliodorus Fixed it..and then over it published two updates to my App.

Comment: @Eliodorus this is my app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.revodroid.notes.notes